# Can Template::Toolkit pretty-print the HTML it outputs?

Tags: html, perl, template-toolkit

I guess the answer is *yes*, but what’s the easiest way to do it? I use `Template::Toolkit::Simple`, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but since it's based on a template - just make your template pretty printed.

Comment: The Zen in this answer is beatiful.

Comment: Except that it doesn’t work, for example when you have a HTML fragment that’s being inserted dynamically in existing HTML context and has to be reformatted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create pretty-print HTML then you have to use [Template::Plugin::HTML](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aHTML) instead of Template::Toolkit::Simple.

You may also try these approaches: [Template::Flute](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aFlute) and [Markapl](https://metacpan.org/module/Markapl)